# Prev. and Next button Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

In the attached jsfiddle you can find a pagination.

```
[jsfiddle.net/3u64cx2s/4/][1]
```

The pagination itself (1,2,3) works perfectly. 
However, the previous and next buttons don't work the way they should.

For example if I am on page 1 and click the previous button it goes to an "empty" sheet. The same happens when I am on page 3 and click the next button.
Furthermore, if I click a few times on the previous or next button then it leads me back to a page where it shows "head7" to "head9" which shouldn't appear at all.

I hope you guys can help me out with those buttons.

Thank you a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in your jquery code:

```
   /* Pagination: Without Buttons */

$(document).ready(function(){    

pageSize = 2;

showPage = function(page) {
    $(".post").hide();

    $(".post").each(function(n) {



            if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                $(this).show();
        });        
    }

    showPage(1);

    $("#pages .pages_1").click(function() {
        $("#pages .pages_1").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        showPage(parseInt($(this).text())); 
    });

        $('#prev').click(prevPage);
        $('#next').click(nextPage);

    });


    /* Pagination: Inlcuding Buttons */


    var page = 1;

    function prevPage() {
        debugger;
        if (page === 1) {
            page = Math.floor($('.pagination .post').length/pageSize);
        } else {
            page--;
        }
        console.log(page);
        showPage(page);
    }

    function nextPage() {
        if (page == Math.floor($('.pagination .post').length/pageSize)) {
            page = 1;
        } else {
            page++;
        }
        showPage(page);
    }
```

Fiddle for support : http://jsfiddle.net/3u64cx2s/9/
(Updated Fiddle)

Comment: Hi Shubham, thanks for looking at my code. I tried your solution on jsfiddle but it is still the same problem :-(

Comment: See new updated answer this time it works perfectly f9

Comment: Hi shubham, I am sorry to bug you but there is still some problem with it. For example if you click on the next button a few times it it will also bring you to the posts (head7 - head10) but that shouldn't be possible since the last posts on page 3 is head6 and after that the other posts shouldn't appear on the website. Another issue is for example when you are on page 2 and then you click the next button it sometimes brings you back to page 1 or skips you to head7-head8. The same happens with the prev button.

Comment: I think this much code is sufficient to satisfy to your question because your question is not having  that much description as compared to your comments, so try something out with yourself using this code because you can edit this answer according to your self .

Comment: hello Shubham Nigam can you please help me i want to need previous 1 2 3 next last like this pagination want i have post the que but still not give me the answer'

Comment: please comment your question link here

Answer (score 0):

Great code from **Shubham Nigam** but there is a problem with the next and prev function. You use Math.floor() to get the largest integer of the total pages. When you have 4 results per page with 8 total results, it works. But with 6 total results it doesn't because 6/4=1,5 and Math.floor() makes it 1 page.

You have to use **Math.ceil()** in your code to get it work :)

```
function prevPage() {
    debugger;
    if (page === 1) {
        page = Math.ceil($('.pagination .post').length/pageSize);
    } else {
        page--;
    }
    console.log(page);
    showPage(page);
}

function nextPage() {
    if (page == Math.ceil($('.pagination .post').length/pageSize)) {
        page = 1;
    } else {
        page++;
    }
    showPage(page);
}
```